# Can I run JRuby code from one JVM in another JVM?

Tags: java, jruby

An interesting idea came in which I would rather like to do but can't figure out whether it would be possible or not (guessing that it's closer to not, though.)

A script wants to do something like this:

```
process_recursively(top_item) do |item|
  if item.text =~ /evil/
    item.add_tag(evil)
  end
end
```

Conceptually, this would work like so:

```
def process_recursively(item, &block)
  block.call(item)
  item.children.each { |child| process_recursively(child) }
end
```

But the catch is, the real system (which is implemented in Java, not Ruby) actually makes the call to process the item from a different JVM, so that a JVM crashing doesn't destroy the entire processing run.

I know this sort of thing was possible in an awkward way with RMI back when that was still popular, but is there some way to make this crazy idea work for something like JRuby?

Ideally, I would like to have it work for any JSR223 scripting language, but I'm not holding my breath on that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a generic RPC mechanisms such as:

- RMI (via Java)
- CORBA via Java or native to Ruby (e.g. [R2CORBA](http://www.remedy.nl/products/r2corba.html))
- SOAP / web-services

Also, consider a Ruby specific solution such as JRuby XMLRPC - https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/lib/ruby/1.9/xmlrpc/README.rdoc.

This is not the kind of thing that JSR223 addresses.

Comment: I guess of these three, SOAP is definitely not an option as I already know that you can't ship code over the wire with SOAP. RMI can sort of do it, but it's awkward. I remember you had to open a port for HTTP requests on the client and send that as the classpath when you open the connection so that the server can pull code in from the client. And since it can only request class files, the scripter would have to use jrubyc to compile their code which would be run. But maybe it's the only standard way. :(